# How to make DateFormat guess intended century?

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to parse a `String` in "dd-MM-yy" format to a `Date` object. The problem is that it tries to guess the century for the date.

When specified from 01 to 31, year is interpreted as 2000s (21st Century) and 32 t0 99 is considered 1900s (20th Century).

```
SimpleDateFormat fm =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
String datestr="21-11-31";
try {
  Date date= fm.parse(datestr);
  System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
```

Can anyone help me? How can I specify that I am only working in the 21st Century neatly. I am not exactly trying to look for tricks like manipulating the string or shifting the date based on the condition.

Comment: I believe that if you want to specify that all the dates are in the 21st century, you're actually probably better off doing a stupid string manipulation. `s/([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/$1-20$2/`.

Comment: I am curious why the input is in short year format. Can you get the input in long year format? Another option is to add "20" in the year field using regex before parsing the date. (.replaceFirst("-(?!-)", "-20")

Comment: I have implemented it by string manipulation only. just thought there could be api way of doing it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change the century it uses to interpret 2 digit data entry with the [`set2DigitYearStart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#set2DigitYearStart%28java.util.Date%29) method.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
String aDate = "03/17/40";
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
dateFormat.set2DigitYearStart(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(dateFormat.get2DigitYearStart());
System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(aDate));
```

Will print March 17, 2040.

Comment: +1 - Nice find. Hopefully the upvote train comes back around :)

Comment: I was actually looking for this.Although It looks messy (probably I m just gonna stick with string manupulation) but it answers my intended question I didnt knew about get2DigitYearStart(). Thanx

Comment: If you just calculate Year 2000 once and keep it in a factory you can eliminate the cost of calendar operations and hide the messiness.  Works either way!

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"), SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created. For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be interpreted as May 4, 1964. During parsing, only strings consisting of exactly two digits, as defined by Character.isDigit(char), will be parsed into the default century. Any other numeric string, such as a one digit string, a three or more digit string, or a two digit string that isn't all digits (for example, "-1"), is interpreted literally. So "01/02/3" or "01/02/003" are parsed, using the same pattern, as Jan 2, 3 AD. Likewise, "01/02/-3" is parsed as Jan 2, 4 BC.

It doesn't seem to mention any way to adjust the `[-80; +20]` range. I suspect your best bet is to expand the two-digit year into the four-digit form:

```
datestr = datestr.replaceFirst("-(\\d{2})$", "-20$1");
```

Comment: May the API bless our understanding of these holy words.  Amen.

Comment: I understands this but it doesnt really answer my question. Can we have a neat way of telling the JVM if we are working in the particular century

Comment: @Edge: See the paragraph at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Not with SimpleDateFormat, I don't think.  You totally can with your EdgeDateFormat class that you're going to write to solve this problem...

Comment: @Edge: It answers the title of your question. The question of what it does is very different from the question of *changing* what it does.

Comment: @JonSkeet ..yep..I will be more careful with the title of the questions in future ..Thanx all