# Java: format date string "150520" into "May 20, 2015"

Tags: java

I'm using Java 8 on linux with the following code

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMDD",Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate exampleDate  = LocalDate.parse(myDate, formatter);
```

where `myDate` is a String equal to "150520". I'm getting error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '150520' could not 
be parsed: Conflict found: Field MonthOfYear 1 differs from 
MonthOfYear 5 derived from 2015-01-20
```

I'd like to return `May 20, 2015` for example. Any idea what's wrong?

UPDATE

Replacing the date code `D` with `d` eliminates this error. How to format into readable date?

Comment: More duplicates: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36172920/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40388834/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10732297/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/251535/642706).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `yyMMdd`. The uppercase `D` parses "day of year" not "day of month".

[Edit] for the printing part, you could do `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy").format(theDate)`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMDD",Locale.ENGLISH);`

with

`DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd",Locale.ENGLISH);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this format string `"yyMMdd"`. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
D       day-of-year                 number            189
d       day-of-month                number            10
```